# Execute stored procedure before select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to reset my random number seed before executing a SELECT FROM. However, every time I run it, I have to run both statements separately. Ideally, I would like to have the following work:

```
BEGIN
exec dbms_random.seed(6);

SELECT * FROM myTable
ORDER BY dbms_random.value()
END
```

I get an error `Encountered the symbol DBMS_RANDOM when expecting one of the following :=.(@%;` however if I only run `exec dbms_random.seed(6);` it works.

Comment: What are you doing with the results of the query? I'm not sure why you can't just run both the `exec` and the plain SQL query in a script, What does wrapping them in a PL/SQL block gain you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`EXEC[UTE]`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/EXECUTE.html#GUID-A64F29C8-B5C7-426D-82E9-A8E85763F3D6) is a SQLPLUS command, you can not use it into a PLSQL block.

Also, you need an `INTO` to use a `SELECT` query within a PLSQL block. If your query can give more than one row, you woud have to use a `BULK COLLECT INTO`.

Your code could be something like:

```
DECLARE
    something myTable%rowtype;
BEGIN
    dbms_random.seed(6);

    SELECT *
    INTO something
    FROM myTable
    ORDER BY dbms_random.value();
END;
```

However, I do not recommend using things like `select *`; it would be better to explicitly write the columns you need to get.

Answer (score 0):

Also what's the use of an order by in a select into statement which is defined to only return 1 row?

It seems you want to select 1 random row of many which needs a cursor like so:

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR something_cur IS
    SELECT *
      FROM myTable
     ORDER BY dbms_random.value();

    something_rec   something_cur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

    dbms_random.seed(6);

    OPEN something_cur;
    FETCH something_cur INTO something_rec;
    CLOSE something_cur;

END;
/
```

Comment: This should probably at most have been a comment on Aleksej's answer; the version in the question isn't limited to a single row, so not sure why you think that is the requirement? That answer refers to using `bulk collect` already though, if more than one row is needed..

Comment: The original post does not mention bulk collect. In fact, it is syntactically incorrect. Aleksej's answer suggests an INTO clause or potentially a BULK COLLECT INTO. My answer is simply exploring the intent of the original poster. Not sure why you would suggest this should not have been an answer.